# The use of "from" and "among" as prepositions

Tags: grammar

She was selected from among **a** hundred applicants.

Are "from" and "among" both prepositions here? What is the rule of using two consecutive prepositions as we know a preposition is mainly used before noun? Or,

Can we say "from" is a an adverb, and "among" is a preposition?

Or "among from ' is a compound preposition together?

Please, clarify

Comment: It's very common to have 2 prepositions in succession, for instance see [this question on "of around"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58293/double-prepositions-a-rate-of-around-30-or-a-rate-around-30), [this on "for about"/"for around"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23345/for-about-one-year-or-for-around-one-year), [this on "further on in time"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/419894/two-prepositions-side-by-side). Note that it can be hard to distinguish a regular preposition from an adverb or part of a phrasal verb.

Comment: Need further clarification. So, , we can say from is a an adverb, and among is a preposition?  Or "among from ' is compound preposition?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are two prepositions allowed along with one another in the English language?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/359311/are-two-prepositions-allowed-along-with-one-another-in-the-english-language) Here, obviously 'among [one] hundred applicants' is a PP with preposition 'among'. Swan argues that in certain cases, prepositions can take a PP rather than the prototypical NP as complement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are two prepositions allowed along with one another in the English language?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/359311/are-two-prepositions-allowed-along-with-one-another-in-the-english-language) Here, obviously 'among [one] hundred applicants' is a PP with preposition 'among'. Swan argues that in certain cases, prepositions can take a PP rather than the prototypical NP as complement. Example: the cat ran from under the sofa  = the cat ran [from {under the sofa}]....

Comment: See also [How acceptable are prepositional phrases as complements toprepositions?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/599847/how-acceptable-are-prepositional-phrase-complements-to-pps-themselves).

Comment: Yes, "among" and "from" are both prepositions. "From among a hundred applicants" is a PP with "from" as head and the PP "among hundred of applicants" as its complement. Btw, you need to insert the article "a" as I've shown.

Comment: Note that the sentence is ungrammatical. Should be _selected from among **a** hundred applicants_. You need an article before _hundred_, because it's actually _one_ hundred.